# R (Caret) - Error while training "mlpML" model in loop

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, r-caret

I'm using the Caret package from R to train Multilayer Perceptron (mlpML) models.

What I'm trying to do is Forward feature elimination technique and see how mlpML models perform for a different number of features.

That's why I was training mlpML models in a loop wherein every iteration, one new feature was added and fed into the model.

Here is the error I got -

```
Error: Please use column names for `x`
```

Here is my code -

```
ig_features <- c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5")

library(caret)

x_features <- c()

for (i in ig_features) {

  x_features <- c(x_features, i)
  y_features <- c("Status")

  #------------------------------------------ Building Model ---------------------------------------------------
  set.seed(1234)

  mlp_grid = expand.grid(layer1 = 10,
                         layer2 = 10,
                         layer3 = 10)

  mlp_fit = caret::train(x = TRAIN[,x_features], 
                         y = TRAIN[,y_features],
                         method = "mlpML",
                         preProc =  c('center', 'scale', 'knnImpute', 'pca'),
                         trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", verboseIter = TRUE, returnData = FALSE),
                         tuneGrid = mlp_grid)

  #------------------------------------------ Prediction & Evaluation -----------------------------------------
  predictions <- predict(mlp_fit, newdata=TEST[,x_features])

  cat("Accuracy:",confusionMatrix(predictions, 
                                  PARKINSON_TRAIN$Status, 
                                  dnn = c("Prediction", "Actual"), 
                                  positive="1")$overall[[1]],"\n")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing column names for your `x`, which in this case is `TRAIN[,x_features]`. See `?caret::train` documentation, which states:

> **x:**  For the default method, x is an object where samples are in rows and
>   features are in columns. This could be a simple matrix, data frame or
>   other type (e.g. sparse matrix) **but must have column names** (see
>   Details below).